# Storing blocks on C arrays and running them later

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, block

Ok, I can store blocks on NSArrays using something like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[[myBlock1 copy], [myBlock2 copy]];
```

and run that code later by doing, for example:

```
myBlockType runBlock = myArray[0];
runBlock(); // run baby, run
```

What about the C equivalent to this? Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
    typedef void (^MyBlockType)(void);

    MyBlockType blocks[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        MyBlockType block= ^{printf("Run!");};
        blocks[i] = block;
    }

    MyBlockType thisBlock = blocks[0];
    thisBlock();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Operating System allows you to do that, you can assign the address of an array to a function pointer and call the code in the array using the name of that pointer.

```
typedef void (*fx_t)(void);

int main(void) {
    fx_t udf;
    unsigned char code[1000] = "<<machine code instructions>>";

    udf = code; /* UB: assignment of object pointer to non-object pointer */
                /* illegal assignment according to the Standard */
    udf();
    return 0;
}
```

---

As per requests in comments, here is a complete example that works on my computer (FreeBSD 9.2 on amd64)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef int (*fx_t)(void);

int main(void) {
    int a = -1;
    fx_t udf;
    unsigned char code[1000] = "\xb8\x2a\x00\x00\x00" // mov $0x2a,%eax
                               "\xc3";                // retq
    void *codeaddr = code;

    size_t length = 4096;   /* size of a page */
    if (mprotect(codeaddr, length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC)) {
        perror("mprotect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    udf = (void*)code;

    a = udf();                   // call the code in the `code` string
    printf("a is now %d.\n", a); // expect 42, changed by the code in `code`

    code[1] = 24;                // w00t! self changing code
    a = udf();
    printf("a is now %d.\n", a); // expect 24

    return 0;
}
```

To get the bytes for my `code`, I compiled a very simple `int fortytwo(void) { return 42; }` to object file and then `objdump -d` it and tried the bytes that seemed relevant (I don't know assembly language)

```
0000000000000000 <fortytwo>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   b8 2a 00 00 00          mov    $0x2a,%eax
   9:   c9                      leaveq
   a:   c3                      retq
   b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

Comment: your code is so amazing that makes my brain hurts! Thanks! 

Comment: Glad you like it. As you accept the answer from Marcel, I assume you are not really interested in a C answer :)

Comment: Sorry about that, but your answer even being top notch hurts my brain because I cannot fully assimilate and understand that on my DNA. I am still learning C. For example, what the unsigned char line does and how do I store stuff on different indexes of the array? It is not that clear to me because I am newbie in C. Sorry. But anyway I upvoted you twice! 

Comment: I am also intrigued by this - I like it. But @pmg could you please explain a bit more with the machine instruction part? Could you be so kind as to cite a little example with some machine codes that can _actually_ be run with the function pointer to the array? I understand the UB part, but how could we access the slot of the array using the pointer? Again, a little more on the machine code part would really be helpful. Thank you in advance.